# Через Edge сессия и куки работают, через Chrome/YandexBrowser - нет

Tags: php, сессия

Опишу ситуацию:
Захожу из дома на сайт через Chrome - всё отлично, сессии работают, как и всегда.
Прихожу на работу, захожу через Chrome, авторизовываюсь, сессия записывается, но при переходе на другую страницу (или обновлении страницы) сессия пропадает. Меняю браузер на Яндекс - то же самое. Я начинаю гуглить, через phpinfo() проверяю папки сохранения сессий, права - всё вроде бы на месте. Разбираю код на запчасти, вардамплю всё - всё работает, но обнуляется (session_start нормально включается на каждой странице, никаких session_destroy нет, время жизни сессии фиксировано нормальное). Error_log абсолютно чист.

Пробую с телефона (Safari) - всё работает...
Пробую с компьютера коллеги (а у неё Edge) - работает. Пробую со своего Edge - работает.

Делаю после логина вар_дамп сессий и куки.

```
var_dump ($_SESSION);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Через EDGE всё отлично, выводится то что надо.

```
array(4) { ["auth"]=> bool(true) ["name"]=> string(6) "crash2" ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["statusName"]=> string(5) "admin" }
array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "8287c84fc539e39f58d611db7540d9b5" }
```

Через Yandex получаю это:

```
array(0) { }
array(3) { ["_ym_d"]=> string(10) "1654767519" ["_ym_uid"]=> string(18) "165476751977150794" ["MYPROJECT"]=> string(32) "090efd05c6a0cde49f8c3384a87d9f90" }
```

Куки в настройках браузера включены..
Возможно, наши системные администраторы как-то ограничили.. (???, не буду нести бред, не понимаю).
Вопрос: в чём может быть причина и как на ЭТО проверять после логина других пользователей? Вдруг у них такая же фигня будет, будет писать что всё отлично и вы залогинились, а затем - удаление сессии..

Comment: В момент логина в браузерной консоли что-нибудь интересное написано? Например, про отсутствие атрибута SameSite?

Comment: Маленькая поправка: var_dump'лю с редирректом на другую страницу. 
Если проверить сразу же после логина на той же странице $_SESSION, то там будет записано то, что нужно, в любом браузере. А вот потом оно куда-то исчезает..

Comment: И в Edge, и с Chrome есть ошибка "GET http://####.ru/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)".
Но я её и дома на Chrome замечал.
Иногда она меняется на Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) favicon:ico:1

Comment: Ещё несколько раз пообновлял, иногда "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform". Больше точно ничего нет, раз 50 сейчас ещё раз обновился, вдруг что проскользнуло бы ещё.

Comment: Наблюдения: Mozilla Firefox тоже РАБОТАЕТ.  
И в Mozilla firefox, и в EDGE НЕТ ошибки: 
Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

А в Яндексе и в Хроме есть. Думаю, проблема в ней. 
Но в интернете ничего по её исправлению кроме как "ждать" нет... А я даже не понимаю отчего она...

Comment: «раз 50 сейчас ещё раз обновился» — надо не тупо обновляться, а в момент логина смотреть

Comment: При логине в Chrome/Yandex: в момент логина других ошибок нет, кроме этих (иногда 1 из них, иногда 0, 2 одновременно не было).

При логине в Edge/Mozilla: в момент логина всегда ошибка favicon, но всё работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте, сохраняется ли на компе кука PHPSESSID? [image: куки]
2. Если нет, то что по этому поводу говорит Хром? [image: ошибка]
3. Работает ли авторизация в режиме инкогнито Хрома?

Чтобы такая проблема не возникала, сделайте в .htaccess перенаправление:

```
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^site\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Укажите здесь имя своего сайта.

Comment: 1) Не сохраняется, вообще ничего в "Название/Значение".
2) Всё так же, как у вас, https://imgur.com/IJIHYlt
3) Нет, в режиме Инкогнито - то же самое, что и в обычном режиме

Comment: Попробуйте явно указать протокол https.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, проблема была в этом! Спасибо!!

Comment: Добавил рецепт для решения проблемы.